# Ways to terminal to replace all text from one document with another?

Tags: gnome-terminal, text-processing, text

so `grep` gives us all these fancy ways of searching for text within documents, i want to know how you would take text from one document and put it in another document and/or replace the texts that was previously in the other document.

Comment: If you want to replace all text, you can simply copy a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace all text in `file1.txt` with text from `file2.txt` by running:

```
cat file2.txt > file1.txt
```

You can also simply copy the file by

```
cp file2 file1
```

Comment: i didn't exactly make it clear, but to me it also makes a big deal not to change the title of file 2. So `cat` replaces but doesn't add?

Comment: Both ways the result is the same. You overwrite the file.